# One trigger to read from two table

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Can we use two tables in one trigger? I have history table in that i need place data from two tables.

IE.

```
Guest (Guestno, firstname,lastname,address,city, state, zip.....)
Booking (BookingId, Hotelno, Guestno, datefrom, datefrom)
Boogking history (bookingid,guestno, fristname,lastname, address, city, state, zip, hotelno, datefrom, dateto)
```

So trigger i want to create is that whenever in booking table datefrom is updated it should update all info in booking_history table (except dateto....in case if dateto is not entered)

I tried creating following but it gives error because the guest table is not menetioned in this, but i'm not sure where to put

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BOOKING_DATETO_UPDATE
AFTER UPDATE OF DATETO ON BOOKING
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 


INSERT INTO BOOKINGHISTORY
(BOOKINGID, GUETNO, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP, HOTELNO, DATETO, DATFROM)

VALUES (:OLD.bookingid,:OLD.guestno, :OLD.FirstName, :OLD.LastName,
:OLD.Address, :OLD.City, :OLD.State, :OLD.Zip, :OLD,Hotelno, :OLD.Dateto, :OLD.Datefrom);


end;
```

error i get is below. Below is sample but all the fields that are from Guest table (guestno, firstname, lastname, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE)

Error(9,38): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.FIRSTNAME'

Comment: please show us the real (exact) error message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please explain when the trigger gives an error and exact text of the error. As I could see not the trigger is incorrect:
1. IF UPDATEING - spell issue + I don't see why you use it if the trigger is declared as ON UPDATE
2. if you would like to check is :OLD.DATETO whether changed just compare it with :new id. 
3. after IF should be THEN

Try to add these fixes and show the error text

Trigger on BOOKING table could deal with fields which exist in the table BOOKING. You're trying to work with old/new fields of GUEST table that is IMPOSSIBLE. old and new GUEST could be accessible only in a trigger on GUEST table. That's it.

Comment: 1.) I deleted part it says IF UPDATING.....I understand what you say
2.) I still get that compile error. below is sample....but all field that are from guest table has same issue.

Error(9,38): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.FIRSTNAME'

Comment: I update my answer. See it. In a nutshell - it's impossible to do what's you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You trigger can certainly query a table other than the table it is defined on (though putting this sort of logic into triggers makes it rather likely that you're going to be coming back and asking about how to work around mutating table exceptions in the future).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BOOKING_DATETO_UPDATE
  AFTER UPDATE OF DATETO ON BOOKING
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_guest_rec guest%rowtype;
BEGIN 
  -- If `guestno` can change, you'll need to tell us whether you want to use the old or the 
  -- new `guestno` to look up the appropriate row in the `guest` table.
  SELECT *
    INTO l_guest_rec
    FROM guest
   WHERE guestno = :old.guestno;

  INSERT INTO BOOKINGHISTORY( BOOKINGID, 
                              GUESTNO, 
                              FIRSTNAME, 
                              LASTNAME, 
                              ADDRESS, 
                              CITY, 
                              STATE, 
                              ZIP, 
                              HOTELNO, 
                              DATETO, 
                              DATFROM)
   VALUES (:OLD.bookingid,
           :OLD.guestno, 
           l_guest_rec.FirstName, 
           l_guest_rec.LastName,
           l_guest_rec.Address, 
           l_guest_rec.City, 
           l_guest_rec.State, 
           l_guest_rec.Zip, 
           :OLD,Hotelno, 
           :OLD.Dateto, 
           :OLD.Datefrom);
end;
```